# Spree - Admin - Custom Controller - Form Post - Redirects to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am learning spree while building my imaginary eCommerce site. I noticed that there is no way to re order products.So I added a field to the database and extended the model. Things work alright in the IRB/Pry.

Now I am going to add it as a feature to the Spree back end. I added a sub-menu to the product tab and a new controller to do the task. The idea is to show a list of text fields and select and when displaying, order by the field. Sounds simple enaugh.

But when I post the form, it makes me log-out of the admin section and redirects me to the login page. I tried with PostMan (chrome) to make an empty HTTP post and ended up with the same result

**Here are my content.**

controller/spree/admin/product_order_controller.rb

```
class Spree::Admin::ProductOrderController < Spree::Admin::BaseController
  def index
    @products = Spree::Product.order( 'placement_order ASC' )
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

**views/spree/admin/product_order/index.html.slim**

```
= render :partial => 'spree/admin/shared/product_sub_menu'
h1 Product Order

form method="post" action="/admin/product_order/update"
  h3 Select the order of products :-
  table
    tr
      td Image
      td Name
      td Order

    - @products.each do | product |
      = render :partial => 'spree/admin/product_order/product_order', :locals => { :product => product }
  input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match '/admin/product_order'         => 'spree/admin/product_order#index'
  match '/admin/product_order/index'   => 'spree/admin/product_order#index'
  match '/admin/product_order/update'  => 'spree/admin/product_order#update'
```

on post: It redirects to `http://localhost:3000/login`

Am I doing some thing wrong, or am I to do it differently?

Thanks in advance.

Have a great Monday, ya I know... its going to be horrible to most of us :)

Comment: You should rely on form_tag helper not manually write the form and the routes if possible. Follow rails convention, will make your life easier.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what is causing your page to get redirected to the login page.  My guess would be that a permission check is failing somewhere.  You should see if you're getting a CanCan::AccessDenied exception thrown somewhere, which is being rescued, that redirects you to the login page.  It looks like your update action is not being executed, which means that something is happening before it ever makes it to your class.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around it for some time. At first I thought the CSRF token was missing. But then it was in the header of the page.

Then was the forms. Looking in to the forms, they lacked few hidden fields which sounded like security. They were like

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="[long code]" />
```

Understanding I am missing some thing and those some things normally we don't put by hand...

I used the form helper method.

```
= render :partial => 'spree/admin/shared/product_sub_menu'
h1 Product Order

= form_tag( "/admin/product_order/update",  method: "post" ) do
  h3 Select the order of products :-
  table
    tr
      td Image
      td Name
      td Order

    - @products.each do | product |
      = render :partial => 'spree/admin/product_order/product_order', :locals => { :product => product }
  = submit_tag( "Save" )
```

The use of the `form_tag` fixed the issue for me.

In vary basic `hello world` class apps, using a bare form had worked. But I think the new restrictions come from Spree or an other library I have chosen.

Thanks for the advices.